# RSpec: wait alternative to match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, acceptance-testing

There are some articles (e.g. [1]) regarding solving flaky acceptance tests when using Capybara which advocates using e.g.

```
.to have_text("foo")
```

instead of

```
.to eql("foo")
```

In one of my tests I have `.to match(/foo/)` and every once in a while this fails. I assume that the `match` matcher is not in the same category as e.g. the `have_text` matcher and doesn't wait. The documentation doesn't mention anything regarding this.

Is there any regex matcher so that I can check e.g.

```
expect(next_url).to match(/foo/)
```

?

---

**Versions used (not changeable):**

capybara: 2.7.x

spec-rails: 3.6.x

[1] https://www.urbanbound.com/make/fix-flaky-feature-tests-by-using-capybaras-apis-properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for `have_text` link to the `assert_text` docs - https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Matchers#assert_text-instance_method which show that it takes either a string

```
expect(page).to have_text('Something')
```

or a Regexp

```
expect(page).to have_text(/foo/)
```

As the article you linked to implies, if you find yourself using any non capybara provided matcher with information returned from Capybara you're probably doing something wrong, and setting yourself up for flaky tests.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a page where elements have a delay appearing on the page, you can define a 'wait' method in 'capybara_helpers.rb'

```
def wait_for timeout = 10, &block
Timeout.timeout(timeout) do
  loop do
    condition = yield
    if (condition)
      break true
    end
  end
end

rescue Timeout::Error
  raise "Condition not true in #{timeout} seconds"
```

end

After that, you can use 'wait_for' method like this:

```
wait_for { page.has_css?('.class', text: 'Something') }
```

Comment: This will add to the overall test time if used by the whole team in several cases, that's why we avoid this construct.

Comment: I totally agree with you. But in some cases, this method is useful, especially if you have some animations that appear with a delay on the page and you need to check them.